# Getting started with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to asp.net mvc. I have lot of experience in asp.net web forms. Can any one please help me find a good resource to getting started with MVC 5?

Comment: I really dislike when people use the word "professional" in this context.  What makes a project professional /sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to all the great answers, I would like to add a few things...

As a consultant working in many different companies, I’ve had my chance to get my hands dirty on many different asp.net MVC applications.

One of the first things I realize is that people’s understanding (or lack thereof) of asp.net MVC varies a lot and this has a major impact on the way the application is built and maintained.

For the past 13 years or so, Microsoft has been teaching us how to build websites using webforms. That is by dragging and dropping controls, double-clicking it and code against that.

When asp.net MVC was first introduced (a while back), people’s initial reaction was to not fully understand why we’d want to intermingle server-side code with HTML. After all…isn’t this bad/wrong?

More importantly, people would compare this to Classic ASP and believe this is some sort of step back.

Now that more and more people have been working with asp.net MVC, I can assure you that most of them would not return to the webform style of things.

You have to understand that an asp.net MVC project is very versatile and with that versatility comes more responsibilities. It is the understanding of those new responsibilities that people don’t fully grasp. In turn, this can easily transform an MVC project into a bunch of spaghetti code and maintenance hell.

As a quick example, I’m still seeing people not understanding or seeing the benefits of having strongly typed Views with ViewModels. Applications have the tendency of evolving and change a lot. Having ViewModels will help in coping with the scalability of your application and when you need to refactor.

Try to adopt a JavaScript standard perhaps with namespace and what not as you’ll quickly see your Views contaminated with JavaScript.

Adopt the separation of concerns philosophy by having a well layered architecture not only for testability but also for ease of refactoring, maintainability and readability of your code.

As an example, download some existing application such as the open source NopCommerce project. Open the source code, see how they do things.

Answer (score 1):

I learned .NET MVC by watching videos on Pluralsight: http://beta.pluralsight.com/. I have also learned a ton by reading posts here on Stack Overflow. There are also a lot of good learning resources on the Microsoft ASP .NET MVC site: http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to start is http://www.asp.net/mvc and also check 
 [this PluralSight course](http://beta.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals) and also  [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/) has lots of fantastic materials on is blog google is always the best friend.